# Question about global skills + undo in shop

Tags: league-of-legends

Is using the 'undo' in shop an advantage for champions with global skills?

3 scenarios I can think of is :

Say, Ashe has ult and gold around 1600. She can buy the rod for + AP which is beneficial for her ult then exchange for BFSword/Zeal and Boots.

Another is Kart, where he can cast his ult with the rod, then undo after, and go with chalice of harmony + boots.

Last is Soraka, which badly needs her ult, goes for CDR boots, casts ult, undo then go for mobility.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, it's not advantageous for those champions.**

As soon as you perform any action the undo button will grey out and you won't be able to undo your last purchase.

This even happens if you do an action passively (such as Teemo stealth or Homeguards).

Comment: I think it also works on global objections as well had a weird game once actually three one with drag another with a turret kill and then an assist i got from a shroom which i guess is not as weird as the first wo

Comment: Here is a really funny video of HotshotGG trying to do the exact thing you are thinking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYTJeb5rhw0

Comment: "any action" isn't quite true. it's specified in the release notes somewhere, something like `as soon as you deal damage, heal a unit, ...`